# Logic behind plugin system?

Tags: oop, architecture, plugins

I have an application in PHP (private CMS) that I would like to rewrite and add some new things - I would like to be able to extend my app in an easier way - through plugins

But the problem is - I don't know how to achieve "pluggability", how to make system that recognizes plugins and injects them into the app?

So, what's the logic of a simple plugin system?

Comment: a useful way to think of plugins is as a solution to decentralize processing of different formats for the same type of object.  an image viewer will have different plugins for jpeg, bmp, gif, etc.  when a format goes to a new version, or a new file format arrives, (re)writing the plugin or installing the plugin will address the issue far more cheaply.

does this sound like what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally plugins will all implement a common interface. The application using these plugins will load each plugin from a repository (e.g. libraries in a directory) and use the common interface to talk to them. You can extend this such that plugins implement one or more from a set of common interfaces.

Difficulties include determining what interface to define to be useful not just now, but for future plugins. You also need to worry about badly-written plugins. What happens if the plugin throws an exception ? Or perhaps if it ceases responding. Should you allow badly-performing plugins to bring down your system, or should you be isolated from this.